# Comprobar espacio ocupado en Almacenamiento Interno de dispositivo Android

Tags: python, android, windows

Buenas noches a todos,

Actualmente estoy trabajando en un proyecto que requiere verificar el espacio disponible en el almacenamiento interno de un dispositivo Android conectado a la PC. En este contexto, surge la limitación de no poder utilizar ADB, ya que este proyecto está destinado a puntos de venta de información y no es práctico activar las opciones de desarrollador en cada dispositivo de los clientes.

Mi consulta se centra en la posibilidad de interactuar con Windows mediante Python para obtener esta información sin la necesidad de activar opciones de desarrollador. Idealmente, estoy buscando obtener tanto el espacio disponible como el tamaño total del almacenamiento interno. Si existe alguna manera de obtener el espacio ocupado sin tener que iterar a través de cada archivo, sería aún más óptimo.

Agradezco de antemano cualquier orientación o sugerencia que puedan proporcionar. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Bienvenido, agrega lo que trataste o investigaste, revisar [ask|, saludos.